# Mysql Backup Progress Monitor in java

Tags: java, backup, mysql, jprogressbar

Am backing up MySQL database using java. I will like to know if there is a way to monitor the backup progress and then display in percent on JProgressBar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be inserting Java into this in the first place. MySQL already comes with backup functions. Use them. Don't roll your own; don't add unreliability; don't add any code at all. Just define a backup schedule.